# Why am I unable to use my Windows 8 after installing Windows 7 in a separate partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, multi-boot, operating-systems

Previously I had dual boot I.e, Windows 8 in G:drive and Windows 7 in C:drive. Since I had slow performance in Windows 7 I had to remove  and re-install Windows 7 again in C:drive. so while starting up I used OS CD(disk) and while choosing the partition for OS I selected C:drive, deleted volume(existing win7 contents) and performed installation successfully.

Now when I turn on my laptop I couldn't dual boot, i am unable to find Windows 8, but the system files and other contents of G:drive (WIN 8)remains. While I check in system settings it doesn't show G:drive as a  system partition but a primary partition. I have few important software configured properly in Windows 8 which is my main concern right now. I desperately need Windows 8 now.

Please somebody help me sort out this.

Comment: Please run msconfig.exe and share a screenshot showing a Boot tab at System Configuration windows.

Comment: how do i share a screenshot?? its not copying here after ctrl+alt+prtscr. @Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot a Window 8 installation media (from DVD or USB) and do a startup repair. That should fix it.

When you install (re-install) an older Windows version it will overwrite the bootloader of a newer Windows version (or any non-Microsoft OS) in such a way the newly installed OS is the only bootable OS on the system.

The repair from the Window 8 medium will, in most cases, find the Windows 7 install and integrate it with the Windows 8 boot-loader so you can boot both.

Comment: hope it will help me out..il try doing it. @tonny

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Download Easy bcd Software and use it. Add a new boot entry using that software. You just need to select your partition where your windows 8 is installed.

Answer (score -1):

When you open `msconfig`, do you see your Windows 8 installation ? 
Your setting for OS display at start up time may be set to '0' seconds and/or you should be able to see the Windows 8 and set it as default OS on start up.